# sh script to replace all file names and folder names on mac

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have to replace all file and folder names in a directory and it's subdirectory on mac.

For example;
If I run `./rename.sh gmail street` on mac console, Directory structure should change from

```
root->gmail->a.gmail
           ->b.gmail
    ->email->ww.email.g
           ->gmail.e
```

To

```
root->street->a.street
           ->b.street
    ->email->ww.email.g
           ->street.e
```

I found out changing all file names script

```
for f in *;
 do 
   echo mv "$f" "${f/$1/$2}";
 done
```

But have no idea how to change all file names and folder names of a directory and it's sub. Any suggestion will appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` to recurse through subdirectories. It's a little hairy because you need to explicitly invoke a subshell to get the replacements to work.

```
find . -name "*$1*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/$2/$3}"' bash {} "$1" "$2" \;
```

Explanation:

- `-name "*$1*"` finds files and directories containing "gmail".
- `mv "$1" "${1/$2/$3}"` is executed for each file.
- The safest way to pass variables to a subshell is via positional arguments: `bash -c "cmd" arg0 arg1 arg2 arg3`. `arg0` becomes `$0` inside the subshell, `arg1` becomes `$1`, etc. So:

  1. `bash` is `$0` inside the subshell (unused).
  2. `{}`, the current file name, is `$1` inside the subshell.
  3. `$1`, the first argument to your script ("gmail"), is `$2` inside the subshell.
  4. `$2`, the second argument to your script ("street"), is `$3` inside the subshell.

  This may be confusing. What you want to keep in mind is that `$1` inside `'mv "$1" "${1/$2/$3}"'` is not the same as `$1` outside. These are two different values.
- `\;` denotes the end of the `-exec` action.

Comment: Great Thanks. worked well. One question , in your answer how $2 and $3 became original parameter? I think $1 and $2 are origin parameters.